# mysql clusterset vs replication

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

We run a medium sized app which may need the potential to grow but for a few years a single Mysql server would be sufficient. However we host on Azure which twice in the last 6 months has gone down and I don't want our primary product to be offline!!

I've been reading about InnodDB clusters and wondering why someone wouldn't use this (but with a single node) vs master/slave single server-server replication?

From what it now seems, I would setup 2 clusters in different locations, if one went offline for X time, I could then switch the replica to primary and discard the now-offline primary. But unless I'm missing something it seems **what might be the key** is that with the cluster structure you can bring up new replicas without needing to turn the primary cluster off?? Is that right? So unlike the server-server replication which would require a full DB copy / paste from former-slave-now-master to new-server-altogether Mysql can handle that copying and setup process in a cluster environment.

I'm hoping that makes sense and my question is on track.

Comment: A million rows?  A billion rows?  What kind of app?  Most apps are happy with a single server.  But maybe yours will be bigger.  Maybe Azure is not good enough?  Did they go down in only one data center, so _that_ is the reason for looking at replication or clustering?  More details, please.

Comment: Maybe a few hundred thousand rows but its more about maintaining availability. A few months back the whole Azure network went down (in Europe) so just want to manage in case it happens again.

Comment: I wonder if the "network" being down would have prevented you from getting to any Replica server.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my query is more about which technology is best for single node instances and bringing up new replicas the easiest.

Comment: Every technology can fail.  Cloud providers have very good records; I don't know what technology Azure uses "under the covers".  For non-Cloud setups, I recommend Galera or Group Replication.